# Using $gt in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to select all the documents in a collection that have 'age' property greater than a given age value.

Not working,

```js
age: {
    $gt: given_age_value
}
```

Working fine,

```js
age: {
    $gt: +given_age_value
}
```

What difference does the plus sign make? I can't find it in docs.

Comment: the + sign converts  **given_age_value** (if it's something other than a valid number) to a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the `given_age_value` is not a number (string may be) and adding + before makes it to a number.

`{$gt: "1"}` doesn't work

`{$gt: 1}` will work

`{$gt: +"1"}`  will work

Comment: Shouldn't {$gt: +"1"} work?

Comment: :D Wrong typo, exactly it works because the + makes it to a number